# Can we configure multer to not store files locally and only for using req.files.image.path?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, multer

My application's need is as follows:
I upload the image to Cloudinary and store the url of image in my mongodb database.

To upload the image to cloudinary, I needed to give the file path, and for that, I am using multer.I use the statement:

app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));

The problem I face is that, everytime I upload an image from my local system to the database on Cloudinary, a local copy gets created in './uploads/'.I want this to not happen, since my images are there on Cloudinary.

I read the [documentation of multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) where it says:

> Multer accepts an options object, the most basic of which is the dest property, which tells Multer where to upload the files. In case you omit the options object, the file will be renamed and uploaded to the temporary directory of the system.

I am unable to make out if that temporary upload space needs cleaning or if it is taken care of.My images are uploaded on Cloudinary.I used multer only for getting :

req.files.photo.path

to work.Is there any other way to do the same or if multer can be configured in a way to not store images to my local system?

Comment: Did you got your question resolved? I am having this same issue. Their doc says use memory storage as a storage option instead of disk. I used it but it does not work.

Comment: @codeinprogress: Yes, the answer below didn't work for me too, that is why I have not accepted it. My requirement in the project had changed, and I was okay for the memory this was taking. Do post an answer if you find a way to work around this.

Comment: Have to ask the Cloudinary guys directly.

Comment: This is not specific to Cloudinary. @codeinprogress: Did you try Ruslan's answer below? If that does not work, you can raise a pull request in multer's repo, or in busboy's repo on Github asking your doubt. Do post back your solution here, so it may help others in future. :)

Comment: Yes, I meant multer. I wrote cloudinary by mistake. Will post here whatever they tell me.

Comment: no luck with the multer team to get this sorted. I am using fs-extra module to delete all files from the upload folder as soon as the image is uploaded. It keeps the folder empty.

Answer (score 12):

July 2018:

So if you want to store an image into some sort of database, you probably want to convert it into a buffer, and then insert buffer into the database. If you are using `multer` to process the multipart form (in this case the image file you want to upload), you can use `multer`'s `memoryStorage` to get the buffer of the image directly. In other words:

`var storage = multer.memoryStorage(); 
 var upload = multer({ storage: storage });`

to get the [buffer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#memorystorage):

> When using memory storage, the file info will contain a field called buffer that contains the entire file.

that means you can get the buffer from command like `req.files[0].buffer`

---

I updated a simple repo demonstrating upload images to database without making a copy to local in [this repo](https://github.com/Skycocoo/Store-Image-with-Mongoose)

Comment: I took a look at the multer code (https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and I think that this is actually the default if you don't pass any options. So `var upload = multer();` should be equivalent to your suggestion.

Comment: This is consistent with the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#multeropts): "Multer accepts an options object, the most basic of which is the dest property, which tells Multer where to upload the files. In case you omit the options object, the files will be kept in memory and never written to disk."

Answer (score 3):

Prior to 14-07-2016 you could not configure `multer` to store files locally.

But [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is just a wrapper of [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy). So, we can try use `busboy` directly if we want to avoid hitting the disk.
[Connect-bubsboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) will help us:

```
app.use(busboy());

// request handler
req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  file.on('end', function() {
    // do stuff with req.files[fieldname]
  });
});
```

**Update 14-07-2016**

Now multer has `MemoryStorage` to store files in memory as Buffer.

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage()
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Comment: I don't know if this was true in the past, but now multer offers the `memoryStorage()` object allowing in-memory storage.

Answer (score 3):

From Multer info page at
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

> If the **inMemory** option is true - no data is written to
>   disk but data is kept in a buffer accessible in the file object.

Comment: When it says that one could 'run to app memory,' this is a limitation with server RAM maybe? Is it automatically 'cleared out,' or do we have to 'clean up; memory manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can also delete the file once it's uploaded to Cloudinary.

```
// used to delete images from local directory
const fs = require('fs'); // gain access to file system
const util = require('util');
const deleteFile = util.promisify(fs.unlink); // unlink will delete the file

// in your post request
app.post('/images', upload.single('myFile'), async function(req, res) {
  const file = req.file; // multer gives access to the file object in the request
  // code to upload the file to Cloudinary
  await deleteFile(file.path); // remove locally stored image by passing the file's path  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're storing images with Cloudinary then try using [multer-storage-cloudinary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary)